# Convertir Fecha a UTC en SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, offset

Hola tengo un registro de llamadas realizadas desde diferentes países, tengo la fecha y el país, las fechas están ajustadas a la zona horaria de cada país, pero necesito convertirlo a UTC, puesto que necesito calcular la cantidad de llamadas realizadas en un mes para todos los países.

Lo que me solicitaron es convertir todas las fechas a UTC y tomar esa fecha para hacer el calculo.

Como lo puedo hacer? Alguna idea?

Yo estoy usando esto

```
PRINT DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), [fecha_llamada])
```

Pero eso me lo transforma de la zona horaria local del servidor a UTC, pero cada fecha tiene una zona horaria diferente.

Intente igual con la siguiente función, pero es el mismo problema, me lo transforma como si todo fuera desde la misma zona horaria.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ConvertToDateTime (@Datetime BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LocalTimeOffset BIGINT
           ,@AdjustedLocalDatetime BIGINT;
    SET @LocalTimeOffset = DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())
    SET @AdjustedLocalDatetime = @Datetime - @LocalTimeOffset
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(second,@AdjustedLocalDatetime, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)))
END;
GO
```

**Update 14/12/2018 #1**

Adjunto estructura y ejemplo de la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE [TMP].[PortaCallDetails](
    [ID] [int] NULL,    
    [charged_amount] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
    [charged_quantity] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [country] [varchar](50) NULL,       
    [connect_time] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [unix_connect_time] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [disconnect_time] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [unix_disconnect_time] [varchar](50) NULL   
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[image: Ejemplo de la tabla]

Los datos de la tabla están en texto por que son tomados de un archivo, esta tabla es una temporal de la cual se toman y transforman los datos para la tabla definitiva.

**Update 14/12/2018 #2**

necesito una función así:

```
PRINT getUtcDate(@Date, @OffSet)
```

o con el país

```
PRINT getUtcDate(@Date, @Country)
```

Comment: La opción que propone esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7772191/4092887) dice que realice el procedimiento de convertir la fecha a UTC desde el lado cliente. Voy a colocar un pseudo-código de una idea para ver si es viable: ¿Puedes [edit] la pregunta con información de prueba de las tablas que estás usando en esta función?, es que pienso que podrías crear una instancia de la tabla y le estableces el UTC de acuerdo al país...

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta te puede orientar sobre porqué no debes hacer esto en SQL Server. [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/24aeac2a-e35d-47da-aead-4aa3dfcd5260/coverting-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/24aeac2a-e35d-47da-aead-4aa3dfcd5260/coverting-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql)

Comment: ¿qué tipo de dato es la columna `fecha_llamada`?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave agregue la estructura y un ejemplo de la tabla. soy cociente del "problema" con esto, por eso vengo a pedir ayuda, para agregar la transformación de la tabla la hago por medio de SSIS por lo cual tengo acceso mas funciones e incluso a código C#.

Comment: @jachguate los datos vienen de un archivo de texto plano, por lo cual se guardan temporalmente en ese formado, pero pueden ser transformados a tipo Date

Comment: Cabe aclarar que yo tengo los datos del país de cada llamada, con el cual puedo hacer una tabla adicional con el país y el offset a aplicar. Lo que no tengo es la función que haga esa conversión

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según todo lo que leí y considerando que puedes hacer cambios en tu tabla de traspaso la consulta debería ser así:

```
SELECT 
  P.*, 
  DATEADD(hh,T.TimeDifference*-1,P.connect_time) [LocalTime]
FROM PortaCallDetails P
INNER JOIN TimeZone T ON P.TimeZone_id=T.TimeZone_id
```

Siendo `connect_time` de tipo `DateTime` previamente transformado con `SSIS` y
`TimeZone_id` el id numérico de la zona horaria para mejorar la comparación de tipos con un indice en este campo en ambas tablas

y la tabla `TimeZone` debería ser

```
CREATE TABLE TimeZone(
  TimeZone_id smallint,
  country VARCHAR(50),
  TimeDifference smallint
)
```

Dado que tienes la tabla TimeZone sólo basta agregar la diferencia de horas (*-1) para revertir la hora local a la hora UTC.

---

Una solución alternativa con el mismo cálculo pero pensando en optimizar el código para reutilización podemos crear una función

**Función fn_LocaltimeToUTC**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_LocaltimeToUTC (@LocalDatetime DateTime, @TimeZone_Id Smallint)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(hh,(
        SELECT TimeDifference*-1 FROM TimeZone WHERE TimeZone_Id=@TimeZone_Id
    ),@LocalDatetime)
END;
GO
```

Siendo la consulta mas legible y pudiendo dejar la función para reutilizar en otras consultas

```
SELECT 
  P.*, 
  dbo.fn_LocaltimeToUTC(P.connect_time,P.Timezone_id) [LocalTime]
FROM PortaCallDetails P
```

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias, voy a probar y te comento cualquier cosa.

Comment: Me incline por la primera solución, la verdad prefiero evitar realizar consultas dentro de funciones escalares.